# O que significa esse ponto no código da estrutura?

Tags: c, struct, sintaxe

```
int main(){
    char buff[129];
    WSADATA wsa;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &wsa);

    struct sockaddr_in caddr;
    struct sockaddr_in saddr = {
        .sin_family      = AF_INET,
        .sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY),
        .sin_port        = htons(5000)
    };
}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 3):

Nesse contexto é uma forma de indicar quais são os membros a serem usados. Ele acaba servindo para desambiguar se aquilo é uma variável normal ou um membro da estrutura. Sem o ponto poderia ser só uma variável. É uma forma abreviada de escrever assim:

```
struct sockaddr_in saddr = {
    saddr.sin_family      = AF_INET,
    saddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY),
    saddr.sin_port        = htons(5000)
};
```

Esses nomes depois do ponto são os membros declarados na estrutura em algum outro ponto do código, e  oque está antes do ponto é o objeto.

Outra forma que funciona:

```
struct sockaddr_in saddr;
saddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
saddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
saddr.sin_port = htons(5000);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/MemberInitializationSyntax.c).